# Google Analytics - Manually register pageview using gtag js

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, google-analytics, gtag.js

I'm new to GA. Let me go straight. I'd like to send page view to GA via Gtag.js from my javascript.

What I tried is I added

```
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-XXXXXXXXXXX"></script>
```

to my landing page.

Then added this to my script

```
gtag('config', GA_TRACKING_ID, {
    'page_title': pageTitle,
    'user_id': userId,
    'page_path': pagePath
});
```

I can see gtag js loaded however getting error as "`Uncaught ReferenceError: gtag is not defined`"

When I added this snippet

```
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];

function gtag() {
    dataLayer.push(arguments);
}
gtag('js', new Date());

gtag('config', GA_TRACKING_ID, {
  'page_title': pageTitle,
  'user_id': userId,
  'page_path': pagePath
});
```

it stopped giving the error but not sending pageview to GA.
Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

My Bad. The issue was with GA_TRACKING_ID.
I had one space " " in my GA_TRACKING_ID and it was causing the issue.
Just removing that space worked.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you missed parameters (page_title and so on) in 2 screenshot.

Comment: I missed to add it here. However, I've already added it to my code. Edited question

Comment: @ShubhamSharma How do you check that pageview is sending?

Comment: on the network tab (dev console), I can see that it is not sending pageview. When I added this to HTML document it's working perfectly fine. The issue is only when I'm trying to send pageview from the script.

Comment: @ShubhamSharma don't you miss <script></script>? check GA Tracking ID?

Comment: I added this to external js file hence no need for <script></script>.
Even if the GA tracking ID is incorrect is should at least send the call to Google.
It is not even doing that.

Comment: @ShubhamSharma Correct GA ID is needed for double check in Real Time report. Implementation via external file is not a standard way, so, only you can see the whole story.

Comment: I tried adding the gtag snippet to my partial view which is loaded via ajax request, however, can't see the changes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183613/discussion-between-shubham-sharma-and-ms-easy).